# Weak reference to 'associating' object in associated object

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, associated-object

The following code results in an NSInternalConsistencyException: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7fd3a1010000 of class UIScrollView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.`.

Practically, the issue is that when `dealloc` is called on Observer, the reference it holds to UIScrollView has already been nillified, and the `_removeObservers` is a no-op.

I understand that this might have to do with the way the associated objects are deallocated, but this is actually not clear from https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011-322/ (38:14) where the associated objects are erased **before** the weak reference are erased.

A workaround I have found is to make the UIScrollView property `unsafe_unretained`.

- Does someone know precisely why this happens?
- What is the recommended solution here?

Thanks!

```
@interface Observer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end

@implementation Observer

- (void)dealloc {
    [self _removeObservers];
}

- (void)setScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_scrollView) {
        [self _removeObservers];
    }
    _scrollView = scrollView;
    [self.scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {}

- (void)_removeObservers {
    [self.scrollView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"];
}

@end

@interface UIScrollView (Test)
@end

@implementation UIScrollView (Test)

- (void)test_setup {
    Observer *observer = [Observer new];
    observer.scrollView = self;
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"observer", observer, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

And then:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
[scrollView test_setup];
// scrollView is deallocated <--- EXCEPTION
```